# Does disable refresh work in Power Bi service?

Tags: powerbi

I remember reading that disabling the refresh on a table in Power query is a Power bi desktop only feature. That is - it is applicable only for Power bi desktop data refresh.

Irrespective of this setting, the power bi portal will still refresh the table. Is this still valid concept? Or has it changed in recent Power bi verison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the docs:

> Any queries excluded from refresh are also excluded in automatic
> refresh in the Power BI service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-include-in-report-refresh